# Find the Laurent series of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ centered around $i$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

I am having trouble with finding the Laurent series of the following function, centered around $i$:

> $$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} .$$

I tried transforming this into a form that would be appropriate for a geometric series, but was not able to.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = x - i$. Then
$$ f = \frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{1 + (i + z)^2} = \frac{1}{z^2 + 2iz} = \frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{z + 2i}
$$
We are trying to find its series expansion at $z = 0$. Let's temporarily discard the first factor. Since $1/(z+2i)$ is holomorphic,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z + 2i} &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j \\
1 &= \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{j-1} z^j + 2i \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j \\
&= 2i a_0 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty (a_{j-1} + 2i a_j) z^j
\end{align*}$$
Substituting $z = 0$ yields $a_0 = -i/2$. Since all other terms are $0$, we can establish a recurrence relation
$$ a_j = \frac{i}{2}a_{j-1} = -\left( \frac{i}{2} \right)^{j+1}
$$
Therefore,
$$ \frac{1}{z + 2i} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty -\left( \frac{i}{2} \right)^{j+1} z^j
$$
Don't forget to reintroduced the $z^{-1}$ term and substitute $z = x - i$.

Comment: Thank you! I considered using a substitution here but had troubles with putting this into the appropriate form.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Use the Method of Partial Fractions to find the coefficients in the decomposition
$$\frac{1}{1 + x^2} = \frac{A}{1 + i x} + \frac{B}{1 - i x} .$$
NB that since the left-hand side is real, so is the right-hand side, and hence $B = \bar{A}$.

Comment: Alright. So I found that $A=B=1/2$. With the second term, I have $\frac{1/2}{1+1-ix-1}$=$\frac{1/2}{2-ix-1}$=$\frac{1/2}{2-(ix+1)}$=$\frac{1/2}{2-i(x-i)}$. However, I cannot seem to be able to do that with the first term.

Comment: Which Laurent series are you looking for? The one that converges in a punctured disk around $i$ or the one that converges far away from $i$?